# Absolute value of the sum of two absolute values real analysis proof

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value, formal-proofs

This proof seems to be giving me much trouble. I know I must split it up into various cases, with no loss of generality probably fewer but after that I really have no clue.
$||x|-|y|| \le |x-y|$

Thanks ahead everyone.$\:\:\:\:$

Comment: Presumably it should be $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$.

Comment: yeah the inequality should be the other way. my bad

Comment: Well, you can be slick. wolog $|x| = |x - y + y| \le |x-y| +|y|$ so $ |x| - |y| \le |x - y|$ and same for $|y| \le |y - x| +|x|$ so $|y| - |x| \le |x-y|$.   But I always screw it up when I try it so I usually find it easier to break it in four cases and ....

Comment: This works since I already proved the triangle inequality. Once I get to that point just using the additive inverse on the absolute values work since |x| is real and so is |y|. Cool then i just need to split it up into 4 cases and thats it.

Comment: The result is true more generally, for any norm we have $|\|x\|-\|y\| | \le \|x-y\|$. It is a useful result that shows that a norm is Lipschitz continuous with rank one.

Answer (score 1):

$|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$ and $|y|-|x| \le |x-y|$. Since $||x|-|y||= \text{either } |x|-|y| \text{ or } |y|-|x|$, the desired result follows.

So, you don't need need to split up into various cases.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Triangle inequality gives.
$$
|x| = |(x-y) + y| \leq |x-y| + |y| \implies |x| - |y| \leq |x-y|.
$$
I will leave the rest to you.